# How can I copy a .sql file to a Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, confluence, nas, synology

I have installed confluence and postgres on synology nas using docker. Both run succesfully. Now I have to copy the data from a .sql file to the database that I have created in postgres.

How can I do this? I tried looking up different things but nothing helps.

regards

Comment: `psql -U your_username -d your_database_name -h your_server_hostname -f your_script.sql`

Comment: I tried it but it does not find the  sql file. i'm connecting to synology with ssh. I have copied the sql file to synology but it still does not find it @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 1):

Use could use [psql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) and let read commands from the file and execute this in your database. --file=? will do the trick.

Comment: How do you mean? I'm really new to psql :/

Comment: Did you read the manual? Did you install/start psql? And what messages did you get?

Comment: The database is on synology and the sql file is from my local desktop, the command won't find the sql file.

Comment: So you have install psql (or any other PostgreSQL client) on your local desktop. Or copy the file to your server and use a client that is available on the server.

Comment: yes I use SSH to connect to synology and then to the database. I have copied the file to synology but in my terminal it won't show the file

Comment: And what client do you use? And where is the client located? On your server or desktop?

Comment: I just used cmd and then 'ssh admin@ipofserver -p22' . I have installed postgres on Synology using docker image

Comment: Ok, but without using psql (or any other client) you will never be able to execute a sql-file on your database server.

Comment: I can use psql commands. I'm new to this thats why I don't know much about it

Comment: And what happens when you start using these psql commands? Are you connected to the correct database?

Comment: yes, i have also tried the scp command to copy the sql file from my local to the synology NAS file. But I still cannot see the file in my ssh terminal but i see the file on the synology NAS